# Recreating the Processing map function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to recreate the [map function](http://www.processing.org/reference/map_.html) that is used in Processing in Javascript.
It never crashes, I just get bad output.

Below you'll find the function I'm currently using. I'm totally stuck here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The top two lines are specifically in case any of the numbers are out of the function's range.

```
function map(number, loworig, highorig, lowconversion, highconversion)
{
    if (number < loworig) number = loworig;
    else if (number > highorig) number = highorig;

    var num = highorig-loworig;
    var newnum = number-num;

    var ratio = newnum/num;

    var convnum = highconversion - lowconversion;
    var newconv = convnum*ratio;

    var result = newconv + convnum;

    return result;
}
```

EDIT: I just looked back on my code, and I did some hardcoded number shifting to get it to work the times it worked. Basically, my guess is nothing about this function is correct, but I can't seem to figure out why it wouldn't work.

Comment: `newnum = number-num` and `result = newconv + convnum` look odd to me. I had expected `newnum = number - loworig` and `result = newconv + lowconversion`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/processing/source/browse/trunk/processing/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java?r=10811#5086) (with minor reformatting on comment):

```
  /**
   * Re-maps a number from one range to another. In the example above,
   * the number '25' is converted from a value in the range 0..100 into
   * a value that ranges from the left edge (0) to the right edge (width)
   * of the screen.
   *
   * Numbers outside the range are not clamped to 0 and 1, because
   * out-of-range values are often intentional and useful.
   */
  static public final float map(float value,
                                float start1, float stop1,
                                float start2, float stop2) {
    return start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1));
  }
```

So converted to JavaScript:

```
function map(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2) {
    return start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1));
}
```